# What's inside a peak expiratory flow meter, and what's the difference with an anemometer?

Tags: airflow

The peak expiratory flow meter is usually used to manage asthma. I wonder what's inside it and how can it measure peak flow?

[image: peak expiratory flow meter]

What's the difference between this and an anemometer? Can an anemometer be used to do this work? Or is there something can be used to DIY one (like small computer fan)?

[image: anemometer]

Comment: So, how do the flow rates and the velocities compare between the items?